# Crontab doesnt work, system doesnt reboot

Tags: cron, fedora

yesterday i created simple crontab tasks. I think is written proper. Today I logged into my server and check up time. My crontab tasks doesn't work, because at the night system doesn't reboot. Of course i know that, server reboot is useless, but i want do this only for test.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
  2 57  *  *  * root dnf check-update && dnf upgrade -y
  3 33  *  *  * root reboot
  3 44  *  *  * root ./backup.sh
  4 15  *  *  * root screen -dmS minkraft java -Xincgc -Xmx1555M -jar /minkraft/bukkit.jar nogui
```

Comment: Please post text as text and use the format options provided here instead of posting screenshots of text.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. `dnf` is a Fedora/CentOS package management command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused **minute** and **hour** values in your crontab jobs.
The first three jobs might not work propperly due to this issue.

For example:

`3 33 * * *` = 3 minute 33 hour -> Won't work!

`33 3 * * *` = 33 minute 3 hour  -> Change it like this.